# Inserting into cassandra table from spark dataframe results in org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java' Error

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using spark-sql.2.4.1v, datastax-java-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.4.1.jar and java8.

I create the **cassandra table** like this:

```
create company(company_id int PRIMARY_KEY, company_name text);
```

**JavaBean** as below:

```
class CompanyRecord(
 Integer company_id;
 String company_name;
//getter and setters
//default & parametarized constructors
)
```

The **spark code** below saves the data into cassandra table:

```
Dataset<Row> latestUpdatedDs = joinUpdatedRecordsDs.select("company_id", "company_name"); /// select from other source like xls sheet

Encoder<CompanyRecord> comanyEncoder =  Encoders.bean(CompanyRecord.class);         
Dataset<CompanyRecord> inputDs = latestUpdatedDs.as(comanyEncoder );


 inputDs 
        .write()
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
        .option("table","company")
        .option("keyspace",  "ks_one")
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .save();
```

Giving **error** like below:

> Caused by: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 562, Column 35: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 562, Column 35: A method named "toString" is not declared in any enclosing class nor any supertype, nor through a static import
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$expressions$codegen$CodeGenerator$$doCompile(CodeGenerator.scala:1304)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anon$1.load(CodeGenerator.scala:1376)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anon$1.load(CodeGenerator.scala:1373)
>           at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
>           at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)

**Question:**

How to figure out what is wrong here? And how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i can understand :

Line 562, Column 35: A method named "toString" is not declared in any enclosing class nor any supertype.

**This might be the issue,you might need to override toString of CompanyRecord class and also Spark works on custom objects which implement Serializable interface as mentioned in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html.**

This 2 things should solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

This issue comes when there is a mismatch of data types i.e what you defined in table and what your bean/dataframe try to insert into.

Once I correct the data types properly the issue resolved.

Comment: Yes then its self explanatory that the columns and datatypes in CompanyRecord  class need to be match the db column names and datatypes.